# Using Ajax to send post data to controller

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I'm try to get a dropdown menu filled based on another dropdown menu value with AJAX. But I can't get it working. Hopefully you guys can point me in the right direction.

**MODEL:**

```
function get_all_classes($gradeid)
{
    $this->db->where('grade_id', $gradeid);
    $query = $this->db->get('classes');
    $result = $query->result();

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $options[$row->id] = $row->name;
    }

    return $options;
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
<?php
echo form_dropdown('grades', $grades, '', 'id="grades"');
?>

    //This dropdown is filled based on the selection from my 'grades' dropdown menu
<?php
echo form_dropdown('classes', $classes, '', 'id="classes"');
?>
```

**CONTROLLER:**
    function registerform()
    {
        $this->load->model('school_info_model');

```
    if ($query = $this->school_info_model->get_all_grades())
    {
        $data['grades'] = $query;
    }

    if ($query = $this->school_info_model->get_all_classes($this->input->post('gradeid')))
    {
        $data['classes'] = $query;
    } 

    $data['main_content'] = 'register_form_view';
    $this->load->view('template/template.php', $data);
}
```

**AJAX:**

```
var gradeid = $('#grades').val();

$("#grades").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/login/registerform' ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: gradeid,
        succes: function(){
            alert('dadasd');
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** Updated ajax code

Comment: please alert you gradeid that is given in ajax, Is it getting?

Comment: Is your ajax actually ever being called?  I don't see any code that actually runs it.  Is it wrapped in a submit function somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need some sort of bind event for your Ajax, like this:

```
$('#link').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/login/registerform' ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: gradeid,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set your gradeid inside the change so that it gets changed every time someone changes that field since you will be dynamically setting the other dropdown...then you are going to need to change the options based on what you retrive...so you need a callback for when your ajax returns...you should also probably have contengiencies for errors and such, but you can read more about that here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$("#grades").change(function(){
    var gradeid = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/login/registerform' ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: gradeid
    }).done(function(data) {
        //set your returned data to your options for classes
    });
});
```

Comment: Now I get a full html page back how can I only get the data back I need, so the options?

Comment: That's because your method you are calling 'registerform' in your ajax call is returning a view...First option: you should create a new method called 'get_grades' (or something more descriptive) and call that via ajax...then just return the array from your query.  Second option: is to detect in your controller (registerform) whether or not it's an ajax request using `$this->input->is_ajax_request()` and if so, return array from query, and if not return entire view/data. That way you can use the same method. I prefer separate methods...cleaner.